# Exporting point shapefile from ArcGIS for Desktop to R?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, r, export

I am having several problems in exporting my point shapefile from ArcGIS 10 to R.

I tried to save the shapefile as a CSV, but R reads all in one row; somebody in another question answered to use GDAL: I don't know where to find GDAL and furthermore my R version does not have this package; I tried to save it as a .txt but it says "an error occurred exporting the table".. I am out of ideas, nothing seems to work.

Can anybody give me a little help?

Comment: I have some [tutorials](http://evansmurphy.wix.com/evansspatial) on using spatial data in R on my website.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest swapping your search terms to look for tutorials on loading a shapefile into R, rather than exporting a shapefile from ArcGIS into R.

This **[link](http://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/ReadWriteESRIShapeFiles)** should get you started.